# Ansible - How to install

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am working with ansible and I want to install tomcat to 2 other ubuntu machines (webserver1, webserver2).

I have a this hosts file:

```
[group1]
10.40.0.168 ansible_ssh_user=user1

[group2]
10.40.0.83 ansible_ssh_user=user2
```

And I have this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: install apache
      apt: name=apache2 update_cache=yes state=latest
```

No this works fine just for one host when I use this command:

```
ansible-playbook apache3.yml --ask-sudo-pass
```

Because I return one password.

But what's the better/easiest way to make it work for multiple users, with multiple passwords?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/560106/how-can-i-implement-ansible-with-per-host-passwords-securely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the ssh and sudo password while defining the webservers itself

```
[group1]
ansible_host=10.40.0.168 ansible_ssh_user=user1 ansible_ssh_pass=***** ansible_sudo_pass=*****

[group2]
ansible_host=10.40.0.83 ansible_ssh_user=user2 ansible_ssh_pass=***** ansible_sudo_pass=*****
```

[Reference](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html)